# Get attachments with IMAP

Tags: php, imap, email-attachments, laminas

Hello Im trying to get all email Attachments from my email inbox with the [PHP Laminas Framework](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-mail/read/) I tried this but it wouldn't work im not sure why... how do i extract attachments with laminas from emails?

```
    use Laminas\Mail\Storage\Imap;
    use Laminas\Mail\Exception;
    
    $mail = new Imap(array(
        'host'    => 'outlook.office365.com',
        'port'    => '993',
        'user'    => 'lorem@lorem.com',
        'password'    => 'lorem123',
        'ssl'    => 'SSL'));

    $numMessages = $mail->countMessages();
    
    while($numMessages) {
        $part = $mail->getMessage($numMessages);
        while ($part->isMultipart()) {
            $part = $mail->getPart(2);
        }
        echo 'type: ' . strtok($part->contentType, ';') . "\n";
        echo "content:\n";
        echo $part->getContent();
    }
```

> fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Laminas\Mail\Storage\Imap::getPart() in /var/www/html/face/views/class.Email.php:94 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/face/inc/inc.ClassView.php(57): Face_View_Email->show() #1 /var/www/html/face/out/out.Email.php(20): Face_View->__invoke() #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/face/views/class.Email.php

Comment: Your loop appears infinite.  You never change numMessages....

Comment: Yes you're right but this isn't the issue im looking for i already fixed that, something is wrong with the multipart thingy i think...  it just doesn't work ...

Comment: I'm getting: Fatal error
: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Laminas\Mail\Storage\Imap::getPart() in ...

Comment: Please start by editing your full error into your question so e can help.